# No se marcan dias marcados como evento Calendario IOS

Tags: calendar

Apreciados Compañeros: Me he encontrado con un problema y necesito ayuda.

Tengo un calendario creado para eventos realizado en cordova. Y en android va perfecto, adjunto imagen de muestra. Donde vemos los dias marcados como se espera.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El codigo es éste:

```js
   events_container.empty();

        i = 0;

        while ( i < app.database.eventos.length ) {

            event = app.database.eventos[i];
            url_to_go = event.url;
            //date_data = new Date(event.fecha * 1000);

            date_data = new Date(event.fecha_inicio);

            li = $('<li/>');

            li.hide();

            timestamp = date_data.getTime();
            console.log(timestamp)
            li.attr('data-timestamp',  timestamp );

            $('#calendar').find('[data-timestamp='+timestamp+']').addClass('event');
```

Sin embargo en IOS el mismo codigo (cordova), me devuelve esto (sin marcar ningun dia):
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El timestamp me devuelve "NaN".

Alguna sugerencia?

Saludos y gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

Se debe cambiar la manera de crear el timestamp

```js
var t = date.split(/[- :]/);

// Apply each element to the Date function
var d = new Date(t[0], t[1]-1, t[2], t[3], t[4], t[5]);
var actiondate = new Date(d);
```

and dont forget to parseInt() for each element of the array new Date(parseInt(t[0]), parse...
Encontrado en este post:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26657353/date-on-ios-device-returns-nan/26671796

Comment: por si a alguien le sirve de algo.